# Post Effects and Transparent background in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering

Trying to use the transparent background with some post effect like the Unreal Bloom, SMAA and Tonemapping provided in the examples but it seems to break the transparency from my render.

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas, alpha: true });
renderer.setClearColor(0xFF0000, 0);

composer = new EffectComposer(renderer);
composer.addPass(new RenderPass(scene, camera));

// Bloom pass
canvasSize = new THREE.Vector2(canvas.width, canvas.height);
pass = new UnrealBloomPass(canvasSize, strength, radius, threshhold);
composer.addPass(pass);

// SMAA pass
size = canvasSize.multiplyScalar(this.renderer.getPixelRatio());
pass = new SMAAPass(size.x, size.y);
pass.renderToScreen = true
composer.addPass(pass);

// Tonemapping
renderer.toneMappingExposure = exposure;
renderer.toneMappingWhitePoint = whitePoint;
renderer.toneMapping = type;

composer.render();
```

If I deactivate the bloom pass I get a correct transparent background but when activated, I obtain a black background. I looked at the sources and it seems that it should correctly handle alpha texture channel as the format is set correctly to `THREE.RGBAFormat`.

**Edit**: After some research, I found where does this comes from. It comes from `getSeperableBlurMaterial` in *js\postprocessing\UnrealBloomPass.js*.

The fragment's alpha channel is always set to 1.0 which results in a complete removal of the previous alpha values when doing the additive blending at the end.

The cool thing would be to find a proper way to apply the alpha inside the Gaussian blur. Any idea how ?

Comment: Can you create a minimal example in a snippet? That would help us see/debug what you are seeing.

Comment: I added an edit as I found where does this comes from but I need to find a way to solve it in a proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and this can be sorted like this : 
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14104

```
void main()
{
    vec2 invSize = 1.0 / texSize;
    float fSigma = float(SIGMA);
    float weightSum = gaussianPdf(0.0, fSigma);
    float alphaSum = 0.0;
    vec3 diffuseSum = texture2D(colorTexture, vUv).rgb * weightSum;
    for( int i = 1; i < KERNEL_RADIUS; i ++ )
    {
        float x = float(i);
        float weight = gaussianPdf(x, fSigma);
        vec2 uvOffset = direction * invSize * x;

        vec4 sample1 = texture2D( colorTexture, vUv + uvOffset);
        float weightAlpha = sample1.a * weight;
        diffuseSum += sample1.rgb * weightAlpha;
        alphaSum += weightAlpha;
        weightSum += weight;

        vec4 sample2 = texture2D( colorTexture, vUv - uvOffset);
        weightAlpha = sample2.a * weight;
        diffuseSum += sample2.rgb * weightAlpha;
        alphaSum += weightAlpha;
        weightSum += weight;

    }
    alphaSum /= weightSum;
    diffuseSum /= alphaSum; // Should apply discard here if alphaSum is 0
    gl_FragColor = vec4(diffuseSum.rgb, alphaSum);
}
```

Comment: I tried this snippet and it works but it makes the bloom completely white. Were you able to get this working with the bloom taking the correct colours from the object?